# Как получить доступ к содержимому iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, find

На странице имеется iframe, находящийся в одной папке вместе с родителем. Внутри iframe имеется поле для ввода. При нажатии на кнопку оно должно принимать заданное значение.

```
<iframe id="userData" src="userData.html"></iframe>
<img id="arrow" src="../Sources/Collections/downarrow.png">
<script>
 $('#arrow').on('click', function(){
  $('#userData').contents().find('#name').html('1234');
}
</script>
```

Элемент внутри iframe:

```
<div class="delivery-data">
    <div class="data str1">
      <input type="text" class="i1_1" id="name">
    </div>
</div>
```

К сожалению, при нажатии на кнопку не происходит ничего. Я пытался получить доступ и менять значения и свойства других элементов, но это так же не приносит никаких результатов.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, не хватает закрывающей скобки в `.on(`.

Во-вторых, не `html`, а `val`.

https://jsfiddle.net/jg3zcqtd/